# continue code after exception java

Tags: java, arrays, exception

I want to input the students data in array which the index is the index that already specified. So, I use try, catch and loop for input the student, but when the user input the data more than the index, I want the program to make them stop inputing but the result will be printed. For example:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

String[] students = new String[5];
String answer = "";
try {
    do {
        //my code to input the students
    }
    while(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
    //output the students
}
catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex)
{
    //the code that let the code continue or print the data from above
}
```

Should I use finally to print the output or is it possible to just add something in above?

Comment: I think your `try catch` should be inside the loop. You will be able to add things and if an exception occurs, you will only loose last entered value. As you coded here, if any exception occurs, everything seems to be lost.

Comment: You shouldn't wait for the Exception, that is bad programming. Instead, incorporate the `array.length` into your looping

Comment: That reminds me that story about a salesman who fell from a building while he was demonstrating how his window where resistant, that resistant you could ran into one without breaking it... and he died. Even if there is a failed safe (Exception), just prevent the case of happening. Or bad things will happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should invert the order of your `try catch` and `loop` :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

String[] students = new String[5];
String answer = "";
do {
  try {
    //my code to input the students
  } catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex)
  {
    //the code that let the code continue or print the data from above
  }
}
while(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
//output the students
```

EDIT : It's the same answer as Shanu Gupta

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly** you should always check `array` `length` before running the loop. 
Better way to do this:

```
String[] students = new String[5];
String answer = "";

for (int i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
    // my code to input the students
}
//output the students
```

Anyways if you still want to do this (I'm assuming that you're bound to use do-while loop and exception handling)

You can `try`-`catch`-then-`break` the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` inside the `while` loop as follows and then print out the student in the catch block.

```
String[] students = new String[5];
String answer = "";

do {
 try {
  //my code to input the students
 } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
  //the code that let the code continue or print the data from above
   break;
 }
}
while (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
//output the students
}
```